# ProtocolException on writing to s3 from spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, dataset

I am trying to read from hdfs location and save into an AWS s3 Bucket as follows :

```html
   spark.sql("select * from  sometbl")
          .coalesce(1)
          .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
          .format("csv")
          .save(s"s3a://mybucket/foldername")
```

But i get this Exception   :

```html
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: null
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1063)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4229)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4176)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.copyObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1852)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.copyInOneChunk(CopyCallable.java:146)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.call(CopyCallable.java:134)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:133)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
        at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
        at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1235)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1055)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present
        at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:96)
        at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:132)
        at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:182)
        at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        ... 22 more
```

Is there a bug in s3 client ? these are versions used
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.7.4",
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.3"

Comment: Vidya Shree this error occurs to me too - did you figure out what was the cause? Thank you.

Comment: I had to include hive jars , once i included them it was fine